# scope variable inside a function in controller is not being displayed in html

Tags: angularjs

I have a scope variable inside a function in controller which is not being displayed in html

```
app.controller('testController', function($rootScope, $http, $scope,
    $uibModal, $window) {

 $scope.show = function(dashboard) {
   $scope.test="test";
   $scope.option.testVisible=true;
  }
})
```

and html

```
<div ng-controller="testController">
<div>{{test}}</div>
```

this `<div>{{test}}</div>` is hidden initially `ng-style="{'visibility': option.testVisible?'visible':'hidden'}"` and then set to true in `$scope.show`

The html not displaying value of `$scope.test.`
The same thing works if `$scope.test` is defined outside function and inside controller.

Answer (score -1):

Your value is not displaying due to very reason that it is placed inside the function. If you look closely, then you can see the `$scope.show` function is not called anywhere in the code. It is just defined.

Now if you don't want to change the current code then you have two ways to achieve what you want.

Call `$scope.show` function in the controller right after defining it.

```
app.controller('testController', function($rootScope, $http, $scope,
    $uibModal, $window) {

 $scope.show = function(dashboard) {
   $scope.test="test";
  }

 $scope.show();
})
```

Secondly you can call the same `$scope.show` function from the `HTML` using `ng-init` tag.

```
<div ng-controller="testController" ng-init="show()">
<div>{{test}}</div>
```

Both ways will call your `$scope.show` function and it will put test variable in `$scope` variable. And it will show on your page.

That is the difference between putting your variable assignment in function inside a controller or just inside controller.